# Ionic List View Edit Array List (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, listview, ionic-framework

I am currently doing an app with a list view. In the list view, the user can edit and delete an item when they swipe the list to the left. I have the delete button working. I am not sure how to get start with the edit button. When the user clicked on the list view, it will bring up the form which the form will let the user to edit the detail inside and then they can save it. I have follow this example in Jsfiddle. This is kind of what I want, but in a list view

```
http://jsfiddle.net/A5xZ9/2/
```

Here is my code for my list view

```
<ion-side-menus>
                <ion-side-menu-content>
                    <ion-content>
                        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                            <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleLeft()" menu-toggle="left">
                                <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                            </button>

                            <h1 class="title"> Details</h1>
                        </ion-header-bar>
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        <ion-list can-swipe="listCanSwipe">
                            <ion-item ng-repeat="data in tempData"
                                      item="data"
                                     href="#/detail/{{data.id}}">


                      Name:{{data.name}}<br />



                   <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                                           ng-click="showPopup(data)">
                                    Delete
                                </ion-option-button>

                                <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                                        ng-click="edit(data)">
                                    Edit
                                </ion-option-button>

                            </ion-item>

                        </ion-list>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-side-menu-content>
```

Here is my array

```
angular.module('app')

.factory('WebApi', function () {

//Dummy Data
var name = [{
        value: "Peter",
        text: "Peter"
    }, {
        value: "John",
        text: "John"
    }, {
        value: "Lucy",
        text: "Lucy",
    }, 

var tempData = [];

//Display 100 item 
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    var selectedName = name[Math.floor((Math.random() * name.length))];

   tempData.push({
     id: i,
     name: selectedName.text


    })
};
```

Here is my button in controller

```
$scope.edit = function (data) {
    var selectedData = data;
    console.log(selectedData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    angular.module('app')

   .factory('WebApi', function () {

    //Dummy Data
    var name = [{
    value: "Peter",
    text: "Peter"
    id: 1

  }, {
    value: "John",
    text: "John"
    id: 2
  }, {
    value: "Lucy",
    text: "Lucy",
    id: 3
   }, 

 $scope.edit=function(id)
 {

  //here you place your function to edit the data selected
  }



  in the html 


   <div ng-repeat="p in data">

   <input type="text"  ng-model="text" >
   <button ng-click="edit(p.id)" >edit</button>
```

i hope you understand it this method will allow you to know the id of the data selected  then you can use the add modal or inputs from other page you use ng-repeat then you pass it as parameter in the function